# Retrieve value from span class XPath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape some information from this website https://www.gumtree.co.za (https://www.gumtree.co.za/a-house-rentals-flat-rentals-offered/tamboerskloof/studio-flatlet-in-tamboerskloof/1005754794350910092234609 this is the link of the property I am taking information from); more specifically I am trying to take information from these span classes:

```
<div class="attribute">
  <span class="name">Bathrooms (#):</span>
  <span class="value">1</span>
</div>
```

I first want to check if the span class has Bathroom in it and then take the value for that. This is what I have right now:

```
bathrooms=response.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Bathrooms')]/span[@class='value']text()").extract_first()
```

However, I do not get anything.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: your code is looking for Bedrooms and not for Bathrooms

Comment: @balderman oh my typo, thanks. Still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to extract all the siblings.
Bathrooms=response.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Bathrooms')]/following-sibling::*").extract_first()

For more, you can refer to this: [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
Hope this helps.